# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, http, useragent

Это мой метод для запроса на сервер, использую user-agent. Не понимаю из-за чего выходит ошибка и как ее исправить(не на что не ссылается)

```
private fun makeUpURL(url: String) {
            val timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
            val link = URL("$url/?packageid=$packageName&usserid=${loadSharedPref(putSP)}" +
                    "&getz=${timeZone.id}&getr=utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic")
            Log.i(str, link.toString())
            urlConnection(link)

            val jsonAnswer = gson.fromJson(link.readText(), JsonAnswer::class.java)
}
```

Возможно ошибка в методе urlConnection()

```
private fun urlConnection(url: URL){
        Log.i(str, url.toString())
        val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2")
    }
```

Вот что выводиться в логах

```
https://millenniumm.xyz/?packageid=com.template&usserid=e043e6c6-0d4d-4812-a61f-9891fcdfb6b8&getz=Asia/Bishkek&getr=utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic
```

Comment: У вас по этой ссылке "Forbidden", а что там должно лежать?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу только сказать, что Ваша проблема Изначально кроется в формировании искомой ссылки (url). Немного посмотрел что вы хотите получить, что видно сразу :

```
$packageName&usserid=${loadSharedPref(putSP)}
```

user в данном случае написано с ошибкой (лишняя "s")

```
&getz=${timeZone.id}
```

тут ожидается что-то другое,а не строковое название (Asia/Bishkek), возможно я ошибаюсь.

```
&getr=utm_source=google-play
```

здесь в одном query параметре два знака "="

По итогу смотрите вашу документацию, какие параметры принимаются на вход, что туда надо передать и в каком формате.

В качестве бонуса, возможно поможет, пример рабочей ссылки:

https://millenniumm.xyz/?packageid=com.template&userid=e043e6c6-0d4d-4812-a61f-9891fcdfb6b8&&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google-play